# Unable to perform custom deserialisation when using a builder

Tags: java, jackson, lombok

I have a situation where I am receiving a boolean value as either a String "0" or "1" from an external source. 
When mapping, Jackson does not entertain this and throws following error:

> InvalidFormatException: Cannot deserialize value of type `boolean`
>   from String "1"

Thus I'm doing following custom deserialisation which works.

Working Example when done without a builder

```
@Getter
public class MyClass {

    @JsonDeserialize(using = NumericBooleanDeserializer.class)
    @JsonProperty("bool")
    private boolean bool;

    // many other fields
}

class NumericBooleanDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<Boolean> {

    @Override
    public Boolean deserialize(JsonParser parser, DeserializationContext context) throws IOException {
        return "1".equals(parser.getText());
    }
}
```

But I need this to work with a builder and writing it as follows. This no longer works. It throws the same error as above. 
Is there a way around this for a builder to work with custom deserialisation? Note that I'd like to stick to using Lombok's Builder unless its not possible at all. Thanks.

Failing example when down with a builder. (which I'd like to fix to get it to work)

```
@Getter
@JsonDeserialize(builder = MyClass.MyClassBuilder.class)
@Builder
public class MyClass {

    @JsonDeserialize(using = NumericBooleanDeserializer.class)
    @JsonProperty("bool")
    private boolean bool;

    // many other fields
}

class NumericBooleanDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<Boolean> {

    @Override
    public Boolean deserialize(JsonParser parser, DeserializationContext context) throws IOException {
        return "1".equals(parser.getText());
    }
}
```

Quick test case to test this out if you'd like.

```
public class ATest {
    @Test
    public void myTest() throws IOException {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

        // test passes if MyClass doesn't use builder. 
        MyClass myClass = mapper.readValue("{\"bool\":\"1\"}", MyClass.class);
        assertTrue(myClass.isBool());
    }
}
```

EDIT: Trying with suggested options as per answer below

Option 1:

```
@Getter
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class MyClass {

    @JsonDeserialize(using = NumericBooleanDeserializer.class)
    @JsonProperty("bool")
    private boolean bool;

    // many other fields

    @JsonSetter
    private void setBool(String value){
        this.bool = "1".equals(value);
    }
}

class NumericBooleanDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<Boolean> {

    @Override
    public Boolean deserialize(JsonParser parser, DeserializationContext context) throws IOException {
        return !"0".equals(parser.getText());
    }
}
```

Getting following error:

> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Problem
>   deserializing property 'bool' (expected type: [simple type, class
>   java.lang.String]; actual type: `java.lang.Boolean`), problem:
>   argument type mismatch  at [Source: (String)"{"bool":"1"}"; line: 1,
>   column: 9] (through reference chain: a.a.a.MyClass["bool"])

Option 2:

```
@Getter
@JsonDeserialize(builder = MyClass.MyClassBuilder.class)
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class MyClass {

    @JsonDeserialize(using = NumericBooleanDeserializer.class)
    @JsonProperty("bool")
    private boolean bool;
}
```

Getting following error:

> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidFormatException: Cannot
>   deserialize value of type `boolean` from String "1": only "true" or
>   "false" recognized  at [Source: (String)"{"bool":"1"}"; line: 1,
>   column: 9] (through reference chain:
>   a.a.a.MyClass$MyClassBuilder["bool"])

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Update 2020-11-03: Lombok 1.18.16 released.*

Starting with Lombok 1.18.16, you can use `@Jacksonized` to automatically generate everything Jackson needs to use a Lombok `@(Super)Builder`:

```
@Getter
@Jacksonized
@Builder
public class MyClass {
    @JsonDeserialize(using = NumericBooleanDeserializer.class)
    private boolean bool;

    // many other fields
}
```

For earlier Lombok versions, you have to customize your builder such that you add the annotation to the builder's setter method. In your case, it works as follows:

```
@Getter
@Builder
@JsonDeserialize(builder = MyClass.MyClassBuilder.class)
public class MyClass {
    private boolean bool;

    // many other fields

    public static class MyClassBuilder {
        @JsonDeserialize(using = NumericBooleanDeserializer.class)
        @JsonProperty("bool")
        public MyClassBuilder bool(boolean bool) {
            this.bool = bool;
            return this;
        }
    }
}
```

Lombok recognizes that there is already a class definition for the builder and only generates code for the methods you did not implement manually.

Comment: Perfect this works! But am I right to say there is no longer a need to annotate the field itself considering the annotation is added for the bool method now? Tested it works fine when I remove annotations for the bool variable. Wanted to confirm is there any reason you annotated on both ends?

Comment: Yes. I just left the annotations there for consistency, but they are not necessary if you just use deserialization.

Comment: I update the answer (removed the annotations on the field).

Comment: I updated the answer with the new `@Jacksonized` approach (using lombok >= 1.18.16).

Comment: I would like to thank you for this Answer. It worked! 
But, I have two models with builder annotation. Where one model (It contains only String variables) is de-serialized without any problem. For one model (It contains only a Linked List), I had to add this @Jacksonized to de-serialize it. Why ?

Comment: That's hard to tell without seeing the source code. If you open a new question, I'll take a look at it.